# Guess the Disney song from the initials number 5

Tags: music

Try and guess the disney song from the initials of the first verse's letters.
I C S W H W
A T D H A C W
T F I L A H T B L O T D T T
Z S C O T
T M E
A W A T R A
D I T A
C Y F T L T 
T P T E B
T W F O I P H
W A I L T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this song

> Can You Feel the Love Tonight, from the Lion King?

Comment: Yeah it is that one was quick. Now i'm gonna do some beatles songs